# Can OpenID session_state be sent on POST?

Tags: oauth, oidc

We have a situation of the **session_state** param on an OpenID Connect/Oauth app is sent on GET. We asked the developers to send it on POST. Developers claim that because standard OIDC/OAuth use 302 redirects, GET is the only option and they cannot use POST?

Is that correct?

- If yes, can you point to the standard doc explaining it? I could not
  find a doc specifying that.
- If not, can you show an example of how
  can POST be implemented?

Comment: Session state is returned in the authorization response. The authorization may be passed to the relying application as a POST using response_mode=form_post (https://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-form-post-response-mode-1_0.html) or response_mode=form_post.jwt (https://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-jarm.html#name-response-mode-form_postjwt). This probably won't work with non web-application however. But the session_state is not especially sensitive anyway.

Comment: Thank you, that helps!